# Custom page template to display all image attachments

Tags: images, attachments, page-template

I am tryin to insert all pictures in media to page. By meaning all pictures, everything added in blog. I ve been looking this feature all day. Is there any shortcode for that or something easy to make it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to [create a custom page Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates), to hold your custom loop output. Create a Theme file, named e.g. `template-all-images.php`, with the following header:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template name: All Images
 */
?>
```

Then, in the custom page template, you need to query for all image attachments. Try using [**`WP_Query()`**, with post type/status arguments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_.26_Status_Parameters):

```
<?php
$images_query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image'
);

$images_query = new WP_Query( $images_query_args );
?>
```

Then, output the query:

```
<?php
if ( $images_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $images_query->have_posts() ) : $images_query->the_post();

    // Normal loop output goes here

endwhile; endif;

// Be kind; rewind
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

For your loop output, if you just want to output a fully formed image, you can use e.g. [**`wp_get_attachment_image()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image):

```
<?php
wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID(), 'large' );
?>
```

(Replace `'large'` with your desired image size, or omit, to use the default size, `'thumbnail'`.)

The entire custom page template file might look like the following:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template name: All Images
 */

// Get the header
get_header();

// Image attachment query arguments
$images_query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image'
);
// Query image attachments
$images_query = new WP_Query( $images_query_args );

// Image attachment query loop
if ( $images_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $images_query->have_posts() ) : $images_query->the_post();

    // Output the attachment image
    wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID(), 'large' );

endwhile; endif;

// Be kind; rewind
wp_reset_postdata();

// Get the footer
get_footer();
?>
```

#### Using your custom page template

1. Be sure that `template-all-images.php` is saved to your **Theme directory** under `wp-content/themes/{theme-name}`.
2. Create a new static page
3. Under the **Page Attributes** meta box, assign the "All Images" template to the page
4. Publish the page

#### Edits

Edits incorporated into the question.

Comment: Sorry to bother, I am not good at codeing. could you be more specific please. Thank you very much.

Comment: About what do you need me to be more specific?

Comment: in which file i hve to put these code in? and how to use in site?

Comment: See updated answer.